# Webcams not working on a Dell Latitude 5285

Tags: dell, webcam

I recently installed Debian 9 and Ubuntu 17.10 on a Dell Latitude 5285 detachable laptop.

The webcams (both the rear one and the front one) are not recognized.
There is no `/dev/video*` file.

I am not sure what the model of the webcam is.

[The Dell support website for this laptop mentions a Realtek IR webcam](http://www.dell.com/support/home/fr/fr/frbsdt1/product-support/product/latitude-12-5285-2-in-1-laptop/drivers).

Below are my `lspci` and `lsusb` outputs, under Ubuntu 17.10, kernel 4.14.

It is not clear to me which line refers to the webcam.

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:05.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Imaging Unit (rev 01)
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Device 9d35 (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:14.3 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d32 (rev 01)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:15.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0116
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

---

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 044e:1218 Alps Electric Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it seems this functionality depends on a new intel driver which will be included in linux-4.16:
https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-media@vger.kernel.org/msg122619.html

Answer (score 2):

A detailed answer to this problem is provided here:
https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-media/msg131388.html
In summary, these "complex" webcams need drivers both in kernel space and user space, and it will take some time before they are supported under linux.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.11. Dell Latitude 5285 web camera is a "new" camera interface IPU3. Other devices with the same interface are surface pro devices some of those [already working in Linux](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Camera-Support).

"To support the camera on this device (Thinkpad X1 Tablet (gen 2)) we will need to use libcamera. However, we likely also need specific driver updates in your kernel, and updates to the CIO2 bridge that have been developed as part of supporting the Microsoft Surface range of devices." answer from this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/653241/492696) about "How to use IPU3-CIO camera in Linux?".

Update 1: It's 2020 and I'm using fedora 36 with Linux kernel 5.17 webcams still isn't working. I tough surface-linux drives wood work for my device but as I found that Dell Latitude 5285 doesn't have same camera sensors as surface devices in this [table](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Camera-Support). It has OV2740 for front webcam & IMX135 for back camera.

Update 2: After [dumping intel ipu data found](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues/326) that correct cameras where apparently [ov5670 (INT3479)](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/laptop-cameras-ov5670-and-ov5693.211578/) and [ov8858 (INT3477)](https://driverpack.io/en/hwids/ACPI%5CINT3477), not the ov2740 & IMX135. Those sensors are connected to TPS68470 ( INT3472 : 05 (PMIC)). I checked `dmesg` and got this

```
int3472-tps68470 i2c-INT3472:05: TPS68470 REVID: 0x21
int3472-tps68470 i2c-INT3472:05: error -ENODEV: No board-data found for this model
```