# Getting webcam to work on Dell Latitude 5290 2-in-1

Tags: drivers, dell, webcam

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Latitude 5290 2-in-1 tablet.  The only element of the hardware I haven't been able to get Ubuntu to recognise is the video cameras.  Judging from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984450/webcams-not-working-on-a-dell-latitude-5285) my guess is perhaps there is no support at this time.

Is that right?

Here is my lspci

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core 
Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:05.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Imaging Unit (rev 01)
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:14.3 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d32 (rev 01)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:15.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3d (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
37:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
6c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
6d:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

and lsusb:

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0424:5807 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1532:0050 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:4014 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:2807 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 044e:1218 Alps Electric Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

hwinfo --usb

```
03: USB 00.0: 10503 USB Mouse                                   
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: POWV.+uuvZOpekiC
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-9:1.0
  Hardware Class: mouse
  Model: "USB Dongle for Razer Lancehead"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1532 "Razer USA, Ltd"
  Device: usb 0x005a "USB Dongle for Razer Lancehead"
  Revision: "2.00"
  Compatible to: int 0x0210 0x0015
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Device File: /dev/input/mice (/dev/input/mouse0)
  Device Files: /dev/input/mice, /dev/input/mouse0, /dev/input/event5, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Razer_USB_Dongle_for_Razer_Lancehead-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:9:1.0-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Razer_USB_Dongle_for_Razer_Lancehead-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:9:1.0-mouse
  Device Number: char 13:63 (char 13:32)
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v1532p005Ad0200dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Buttons: 5
    Wheels: 1
    XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
    GPM Protocol: exps2
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #14 (Hub)

04: USB 00.1: 0401 Multimedia audio controller
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: JKDt.A+UETb5j1v1
  Parent ID: KRJj.mzrV6H7iCbA
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:37:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.5/3-1.5:1.1
  SysFS BusID: 3-1.5:1.1
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "Realtek USB Audio"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x0bda "Realtek Semiconductor Corp."
  Device: usb 0x4014 "USB Audio"
  Revision: "0.05"
  Serial ID: "200901010001"
  Driver: "snd-usb-audio"
  Driver Modules: "snd_usb_audio"
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v0BDAp4014d0005dc00dsc00dp00ic01isc02ip00in01"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #11 (Hub)

05: USB 00.0: 10503 USB Mouse
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: cLrx.E1ssW4L74M7
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-2:1.0
  Hardware Class: mouse
  Model: "Alps Electric Alps Touchpad"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x044e "Alps Electric Co., Ltd"
  Device: usb 0x1218 "Alps Touchpad"
  Revision: "6.05"
  Compatible to: int 0x0210 0x0001
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Device File: /dev/input/mice (/dev/input/mouse1)
  Device Files: /dev/input/mice, /dev/input/mouse1, /dev/input/event12, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Alps_Alps_Touchpad-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Alps_Alps_Touchpad-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-mouse
  Device Number: char 13:63 (char 13:33)
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v044Ep1218d0605dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Buttons: 1
    Wheels: 0
    XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
    GPM Protocol: exps2
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #14 (Hub)

06: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: uIhY.dFBsQFTOFD6
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:37:00.0/usb3/3-0:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 3-0:1.0
  Hardware Class: hub
  Model: "Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1d6b "Linux Foundation"
  Device: usb 0x0002 "2.0 root hub"
  Revision: "4.15"
  Serial ID: "0000:37:00.0"
  Driver: "hub"
  Driver Modules: "usbcore"
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v1D6Bp0002d0415dc09dsc00dp01ic09isc00ip00in00"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

07: USB 00.0: 0200 Ethernet controller
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: EEKG.xnYl+YUVZVC
  Parent ID: PYMB.WSevIRkAXq9
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:37:00.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.2/4-1.2:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 4-1.2:1.0
  Hardware Class: network
  Model: "Realtek RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x0bda "Realtek Semiconductor Corp."
  Device: usb 0x8153 "RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter"
  Revision: "30.11"
  Serial ID: "000002000000"
  Driver: "r8152"
  Driver Modules: "r8152"
  Device File: enxe4b97ac6387a
  HW Address: e4:b9:7a:c6:38:7a
  Permanent HW Address: e4:b9:7a:c6:38:7a
  Link detected: no
  Module Alias: "usb:v0BDAp8153d3011dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFip00in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: r8152 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe r8152"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #15 (Hub)

08: USB 00.1: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: sZmZ.F1ZquY2RN29
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.1
  SysFS BusID: 1-9:1.1
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "USB Dongle for Razer Lancehead"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1532 "Razer USA, Ltd"
  Device: usb 0x005a "USB Dongle for Razer Lancehead"
  Revision: "2.00"
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Device File: /dev/input/event6
  Device Files: /dev/input/event6, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Razer_USB_Dongle_for_Razer_Lancehead-if01-event-kbd, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:9:1.1-event-kbd
  Device Number: char 13:70
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v1532p005Ad0200dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc00ip01in01"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: usbhid is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe usbhid"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #14 (Hub)

10: USB 00.0: 11500 Bluetooth Device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: X7GA.GS0ueMFUyi1
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-7:1.0
  Hardware Class: bluetooth
  Model: "Intel Bluetooth Device"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x8087 "Intel Corp."
  Device: usb 0x0a2b 
  Revision: "0.10"
  Driver: "btusb"
  Driver Modules: "btusb"
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v8087p0A2Bd0010dcE0dsc01dp01icE0isc01ip01in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: btusb is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe btusb"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #14 (Hub)

11: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: KRJj.mzrV6H7iCbA
  Parent ID: uIhY.dFBsQFTOFD6
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:37:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 3-1:1.0
  Hardware Class: hub
  Model: "Standard Microsystems USB2807 Hub"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x0424 "Standard Microsystems Corp."
  Device: usb 0x2807 "USB2807 Hub"
  Revision: "2.04"
  Driver: "hub"
  Driver Modules: "usbcore"
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v0424p2807d0204dc09dsc00dp02ic09isc00ip02in00"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #6 (Hub)

12: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: zPk0.WbJ3tCF4BRF
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:37:00.0/usb4/4-0:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 4-0:1.0
  Hardware Class: hub
  Model: "Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1d6b "Linux Foundation"
  Device: usb 0x0003 "3.0 root hub"
  Revision: "4.15"
  Serial ID: "0000:37:00.0"
  Driver: "hub"
  Driver Modules: "usbcore"
  Module Alias: "usb:v1D6Bp0003d0415dc09dsc00dp03ic09isc00ip00in00"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

14: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-0:1.0
  Hardware Class: hub
  Model: "Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1d6b "Linux Foundation"
  Device: usb 0x0002 "2.0 root hub"
  Revision: "4.15"
  Serial ID: "0000:00:14.0"
  Driver: "hub"
  Driver Modules: "usbcore"
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v1D6Bp0002d0415dc09dsc00dp01ic09isc00ip00in00"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

15: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: PYMB.WSevIRkAXq9
  Parent ID: zPk0.WbJ3tCF4BRF
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:37:00.0/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 4-1:1.0
  Hardware Class: hub
  Model: "Standard Microsystems USB5807 Hub"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x0424 "Standard Microsystems Corp."
  Device: usb 0x5807 "USB5807 Hub"
  Revision: "2.04"
  Driver: "hub"
  Driver Modules: "usbcore"
  Module Alias: "usb:v0424p5807d0204dc09dsc00dp03ic09isc00ip00in00"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #12 (Hub)

16: USB 00.2: 10800 Keyboard
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: Jl0e.WwTgX0FrS+E
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.2
  SysFS BusID: 1-9:1.2
  Hardware Class: keyboard
  Model: "USB Dongle for Razer Lancehead"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1532 "Razer USA, Ltd"
  Device: usb 0x005a "USB Dongle for Razer Lancehead"
  Revision: "2.00"
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Device File: /dev/input/event7
  Device Files: /dev/input/event7, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Razer_USB_Dongle_for_Razer_Lancehead-if02-event-kbd, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:9:1.2-event-kbd
  Device Number: char 13:71
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v1532p005Ad0200dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip01in02"
  Driver Info #0:
    XkbRules: xfree86
    XkbModel: pc104
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #14 (Hub)

19: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: pBe4.xYNhIwdOaa6
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-0:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 2-0:1.0
  Hardware Class: hub
  Model: "Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1d6b "Linux Foundation"
  Device: usb 0x0003 "3.0 root hub"
  Revision: "4.15"
  Serial ID: "0000:00:14.0"
  Driver: "hub"
  Driver Modules: "usbcore"
  Module Alias: "usb:v1D6Bp0003d0415dc09dsc00dp03ic09isc00ip00in00"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

The webcam goes by the label
[**Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Integrated_Webcam_HD**](https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/usb/286/0bda%3A568c/) but I haven't found much regarding what drivers might be needed, or if drivers are needed at all.  I don't see a key combination on the tablet to activate the camera.

Dell appears to have a [guide for Ubuntu.](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln298412/a-guide-to-webcams-on-dell-notebook-and-desktop-pcs-with-ubuntu-operating-systems?lang=en)

edit: I contacted Dell customer support and they believe there are no drivers for the 5290 2-in-1 webcams for Linux.  Ah well.  I'll use it without the webcams for now.

Comment: Same issue on my end, I tried using the HWE kernel (4.18.0-17-generic) and it doesn't work either.

I guess we'll have to be patient, as I don't see any mention of the webcam in ``lspci`` and ``lsusb``

Comment: Also tried ``5.0.7-050007-generic``, no sign of a webcam in ``lspci`` and ``lsusb``

Comment: Also, I think the [Dell Latitude 5290](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201709-25745/) is actually not the same hardware as the 5290 2-in-1, despite having a quite similar name. For example, the 5290 has an Ethernet adapter, while the 2-in-1 doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same laptop and was looking for a fix for the non-working cameras after installing Ubuntu 20.04.  Don't quote me on this but there should be ongoing work on the software stack which might eventually support this kind of built-in webcam.  I believe the internal interface for these is MIPI CSI2, not generic USB (normally supported by UVC driver out of the box).

Again, I'm not an expert but there needs to be kernel support for Intel IPU3 CIO2, which is maybe getting there in [Linux Kernel 5.6](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/media/v4l-drivers/ipu3.html#cio2), plus support in the software stack with V4L2 so on, with software control of focus, whitebalance etc.  I did do a quick test with Kernel 5.6 in Ubuntu 20.04.  Camera still didn't work however instead of showing "No device found" in Cheese camera app, it had a different message something like "Error capturing video".  Its improving but maybe still a while before its supported completely.